# Output time is incorrect than the infile itself

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream, ofstream, visual-c++-2010

I'm creating template vector to read my infile txt (courseofsale.txt) and output it by csv file (output.csv). Everything is correct but the timing is wrong in highest price and lowest price.
 [The highest price timing must be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB90z.jpg)

[while the lowest price timing must be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXTje.jpg)

but instead i got 16:57 as timing for the both. 
Here is my main cpp

```
// MainTest.cpp
//
// Class that runs the main program modules.


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "StockT.h"
#include "VectorT.h"

void highestPrice();
void lowestPrice();
void outputFile();


VectorT<StockT> V1(4000);
StockT S1;
DateT d1;
TimeT t1;

using namespace std;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Main Method

int main()
{
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("courseofsales.txt");
    string line;
    string sDay, sMonth, sYear, sHour, sMinute,sSecond,sCondition;
    double price,value;
    int volume;

    //Reading the text file

    if (inData.is_open())
    {
        inData.ignore(500, '\n');
        inData.ignore(500, '\n');
        while (getline(inData, line, '\n'))
        {
            while (!inData.eof())
            {
                sDay = line.substr(0, 2);
                sMonth = line.substr(3, 2);
                sYear = line.substr(6, 4);
                sHour = line.substr(11, 2);
                sMinute = line.substr(14, 2);
                sSecond = line.substr(16, 2);

                inData.ignore(50, '\t');
                inData >> price;
                inData.ignore(50, '\t');
                inData >> volume;
                inData.ignore(50, '\t');
                inData >> value;
                inData.ignore(50, '\t');
                getline(inData, sCondition);
                S1.setAll(price, volume, value, sDay, sMonth, sYear, sHour, sMinute, sSecond);
                V1.push_back(S1);
            }
        }
        inData.close(); //closing text file
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    int choice;
    do {
    cout << "Please enter your choice: " << endl << endl;
    cout << "1. Retrieve highest share price of the day" << endl;
    cout << "2. Retrieve lowest share price of the day" << endl;
    cout << "3. Generate output file" << endl;
    cout << "4. Exit the program" << endl;
    cout << "Your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
    if (choice == 1)
        {
            cout << endl << "This is the highest bid of the day: " << endl;
            highestPrice(); //calls the method for retrieving highest price
            cout << endl;
        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << endl << "This is the lowest bid of the day: " << endl;
            lowestPrice(); //calls the method for retrieving lowest price
            cout << endl;
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << endl << "Check your file." << endl;
            outputFile(); //calls the method to create output.csv
        }

        else if (choice == 4)
            exit(0); //exit the program

        else
        {
            cout << endl << "This is an invalid choice. Enter again. " << endl;
        }
    }while(choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3 || choice != 4); //Looping for user input till the program exits

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Retrieve the highest share price.

void highestPrice()
{
    double HP = V1.at(0).getPrice();
        for (int i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (V1.at(i).getPrice() > HP)
            {
                HP = V1.at(i).getPrice();
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++)
        {
            if (V1.at(j).getPrice() == HP)
            {
                    cout << "Date and Time of transaction: " << V1.at(j).getDate() << V1.at(j).getTime()<< endl;
                    cout << "Highest price: " << V1.at(j).getPrice() << endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Retrieve the lowest share price.

void lowestPrice()
{
    double LP = V1.at(0).getPrice();
    for (int i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((V1.at(i).getPrice() < LP) && (V1.at(i).getPrice() != 0))
        {
            LP = V1.at(i).getPrice();
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++)
    {
        if (V1.at(j).getPrice() == LP)
        {
            cout << "Date and Time of transaction: " << V1.at(j).getDate() << V1.at(j).getTime()<< endl;
            cout << "Lowest price: " << V1.at(j).getPrice() << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Creates the output file

void outputFile()
{
    ofstream outData;
    outData.open("output.csv");
    string line;
    int c1 = 0;

    if (outData.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < V1.size(); i++)
        {
            outData << V1.at(i).getDate() << "," << setw(5);
            outData << V1.at(i).getTime() << "," << setw(5);
            outData << V1.at(i).getPrice() << "," << setw(5);
            outData << V1.at(i).getVolume() << "," << setw(5);
            outData << V1.at(i).getValue();
            outData << '\n';
        }

        outData.close();
    }

    else
        cout << "Unable to write file";
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `if (V1.at(j).getPrice() == HP)` this is generally not recommended with HW FP types like `double`. Although in this special case, when your data input is well formatted like 2-decimals only, the real double value will be identically inaccurate after import for each element, so the exact equality test will work. About your time output. You didn't post relevant code importing/exporting date and time, or sample data, so no idea, you probably have some bug in your code.

Comment: @Ped7g i got header for the date and time also cpp for both. but it would be long and it wouldnt be mcve :( thats why i didnt include it here, but should i?

Comment: No, definitely not. You can cut out `StockT` class to contain only date/time fields and show `.Set` and other formatting ...  plus few sample data plus values from debugger, how they are tossed around, etc... but I think using debugger may be even faster than asking at SO, as you will probably find out what's going on in `getDate()`.

Comment: i actually use debugging while running the program. but it says nothing about the error. maybe its a logical error? @Ped7g

Comment: What error? The code is valid. It outputs date and time, just different values/formatting than you expect, but from computer point of view there's no error. Debugging means putting breakpoint at the lines of interest, and examining values in variables and memory. I'm not even sure from the question, what is the real problem. Is it formatting "4:57 PM" vs "16:57", or you mean that all low-price datetime should be same? Why? The lowest price probably happened several times during day, so different times are valid.

Comment: the problem was the i can see the infile becos i created it. and the highest was was bid at around 9 am while the lowest was bid at 4 pm. but my output is just 16:57 for both highest and lowest. and there is only one lowest bid @Ped7g

Comment: Probably parsing of input fails. That should be easy to debug, just step over those `sHour = line.substr...` and see what values are send into `S1.setAll(...`, and also how they are stored inside that function. Also check if StockT has correct copy constructor and the `push_back` creates valid deep copy, otherwise the next `S1.setAll` will overwrite the data and any reference of previously pushed instance will show the last data set. And if that's the problem, then you deserve that, for that ugly C-like way of writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it a bit more, if the 16:57 is time of last item, your copy constructor in `StockT` is bad, creating only shallow copy, while you use it in a way which needs deep copy (in `V1.push_back(S1);`).

This is my last comment here, as you didn't provide MCVE, nor does it look like you know how to debug your code, or understand it. Just re-do some basic programming courses and read something about data structures and memory, so you better understand what is happening inside, and learn how to check that with debugger.